# ClearCase find query: does "created_since" look for creation or check in date?

Tags: find, clearcase

In ClearCase I can search for changed files with the command

```
cleartool find . -version "created_since(DATE)" -print
```

However, I am not sure if this "created_since" looks for the check-in date or the creation date of the file. Imagine I have created a file on Monday and didn't add it to the source control until Friday. Now I use said command to find all files "created_since" Thursday. Will it find my file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will find the file based on the check-in date, meaning the date of the creation of the version.

It depends on the [ClearCase Explorer option](https://cloud.githubusercontent.com/assets/634063/6474793/42c3a6a6-c204-11e4-9380-f05d68ab9d99.gif) (also valid for a [ClearTeam 8.x Explorer](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_8.0.1/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.ccrc.help.doc/topics/u_prefs_ccexplorer_details.htm?lang=en)) "**`Preserve file modification time`**"

[image: Preserve file modification time]

> By default, the last modified time of a ClearCase element is the time it was last checked in.
>   To preserve the last modified time during a checkin operation or when adding resources to source control, click the `Preserve modification time` when checking in files and adding new files to source control preference.

If that option was selected, then the version date (which is used by the `cleartool find created_since` query) would be the file last modification date.

Comment: Thank you, second time you helped me with your knowledge this week already!